# Error: Can't run /Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild (no such file)

Tags: xcode, cordova, ios7

Basically i was not able to Archive IPA's , even though i was able to run the app on emulator and also on devices (iPhone5/iOS7)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix/workaround(?) this with:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

if doesn't works try

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Developer/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```